# JetBrains GoLand. Как прекратить выполнение программы?

Tags: golang, отладка, goland

В текущем приложении реализован примитивный REST API. Как мне прекратить отладку программы? В той же VS19 можно просто нажать на красный квадратик(стоп), а в goLand он не горит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускаете как? Добавьте конфигурацию для запуске в IDE, запускайте по "зеленой кнопке", тогда и "красный квадратик" будет активным. Сейчас IDE не контролирует запущенный процесс, поэтому остановить его не предлагает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja запускаю, вписывая в terminal - go build и ./basicREST А как именно настроить эту конфигурацию? Там много параметров конфигураций, я не понимаю, какая именно мне нужна

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/run-debug-configuration.html